# fabric.js - create Image object from ImageData object of canvas API

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to create an image object in fabric.js from `ImageData` object, we can get ImageData from this:

```
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(10,10,50,50);
//ctx.putImageData(imgData,10,70);

// something liket that
var image = new fabric.Image.fromImageData (...);
```

Is there any way to create an image object from `ImageData` object?

Comment: Simply I want to crop an image, and create a new image object from its data in fabric.js..

Comment: I have a way from creating another canvas, but it's not elegant, I think it's better to do it directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me put my idea here, I don't like this way but have no others around -

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 20, 20);

var c = document.createElement('canvas');

c.setAttribute('id', '_temp_canvas');
c.width = 20;
c.height = 20;

c.getContext('2d').putImageData(data, 0, 0);

fabric.Image.fromURL(c.toDataURL(), function(img) {
    img.left = 50;
    img.top = 50;
    canvas.add(img);
    img.bringToFront();
    c = null;
    $('#_temp_canvas').remove();
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: I just pushed cropping support in `toDataURL` (been meaning to do this for a while) — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/c1a818ac33e3927386e792366f3e7bd3abf9aef6 so you can now draw image on fabric canvas, then crop it via `canvas.toDataURL({ left: ..., top: ..., width: ..., height: ... })` getting data url. That data url can then be used to create new image, of course.

Comment: @kangax that solves the problem for cropping, but not for pixel manipulation e.g. image saturation.