# How to save just the image of the canvas and not all canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) 800x600 for example and I use [fabricjs](/questions/tagged/fabricjs) to add one image (200 x 200).

I apply several filters on my image and I would like to save it, but for the moment, I save the canvas 800x600 and I would like just save my picture after effects.

Is it possible?

Comment: how do you save the canvas now?

Answer (score 4):

From the latest version (download and compile it from GitHub), and this one is what you want:

```
canvas.toDataURL(left, top, width, height);
```

Check the question [fabric.js - create Image object from ImageData object of canvas API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799415/fabric-js-create-image-object-from-imagedata-object-of-canvas-api) for kangax’s comment only.

Comment: Thank you, with this.__toDataURL(format, quality, cropping) an extension of fabric.js since version 1.2.4, it is perfect and does it work well

Answer (score 3):

You can use FabricJS's canvas.toDataURL method which works much like html's canvas.toDataURL

```
var dataURL = myFabricCanvas.toDataURL();
```

If you wanted your user to save their canvas to their local disk, you could do this:

- Create an image from the canvas.
- Open that image in a new browser window
- Have the user right-click and save-as the image

Here's code:

```
var win=window.open();
win.document.write("<img src='"+myFabricCanvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
```

Note: if your image is hosted on a different domain than your .html, you will get a CORS security error and canvas.toDataURL will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="rasterize">Convert Image To PNG</button>


//************************canvas to png image**********
    document.getElementById('rasterize').onclick = function() {
    if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
      alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
    }
    else {

      window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
      var gh=(canvas.toDataURL('png'));+
      alert(gh);
    }
    };
    //--------------end canvas to png image-----------------------
```